# How to add the content of the response from the httpclient into a class and return it as List<>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I have a class below

```
public class ADGroupViewModel
    {
        public string ActiveDirectoryName { get; set; }
        public string BusinessPhone { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeIdOriginal { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Office { get; set; }
        public string PracticeGroup { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

and as you can see on the code below, the line ***var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;*** is the same as this below when I put a breakpoint.

```
var data = [{"ActiveDirectoryName":"545756","FirstName":"Timothy J.","LastName":"Shea","DisplayName":"Shea, Timothy J.","FullName":"Timothy J. Shea","Title":"Of Counsel","IsActive":true,"EmployeeId":"19072","Email":"timothy.shea@mysite.com","Office":"Boston","PracticeGroup":"HLB Consulting","BusinessPhone":"+4634645","EmployeeIdOriginal":19072},{"ActiveDirectoryName":"5675765","FirstName":"Matthew D.","LastName":"Shearer","DisplayName":"Shearer, Matthew D.","FullName":"Matthew D. Shearer","Title":"Facilities Manager","IsActive":true,"EmployeeId":"60048","Email":"matthew.shearer@mysite.com","Office":"San Francisco","PracticeGroup":"Office Services","BusinessPhone":"+346567","EmployeeIdOriginal":60048},{"ActiveDirectoryName":"4575745","FirstName":"Michael P.","LastName":"Shea","DisplayName":"Shea, Michael P.","FullName":"Michael P. Shea","Title":"Chief Information Officer","IsActive":true,"EmployeeId":"74251","Email":"michael.shea@mysite.com","Office":"Philadelphia","PracticeGroup":"Information Technology","BusinessPhone":"+4563465","EmployeeIdOriginal":74251}]

        [Route("api/Personnel/UserNames")]
        [HttpGet]    
        public List<ADGroupViewModel> AutocompleteUserNames(string searchText)
        {

            var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            var client = new HttpClient(handler);

          //  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);

            // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            // List data response.
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(searchText).Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                List<ADGroupViewModel> emp = new List<ADGroupViewModel>();
               var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                emp.Add(new ADGroupViewModel
                {
                    DisplayName = data
                });

                IEnumerable<ADGroupViewModel> employees = emp;
               List<ADGroupViewModel> result = new List<ADGroupViewModel>(employees);
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                 return new List<ADGroupViewModel>();

            }

        }
```

I need help on how to inject the value of data into the class ***ADGroupViewModel*** and return the said class as List so that I can
get the values for the ***DisplayName*** property. Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the Newtonsonft.Json Nugget and desrialize your data:

```
List<ADGroupViewModel> emp = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ADGroupViewModel>>(data);
```

I've checked with your data variable and I've got 3 items.